# Error while importing JMX file in jmeter conversion.exception

Tags: exception, jmeter

This is the error when I'm importing the jmx file into JMeter
[image]

Comment: Double check all the plugin jars is available

Answer (score 0):

There's a conflict with your [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-json) plugin against other plugins.

Check [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/mrs1y5SqS0A) in jmeter plugins with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [JSON Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) in order to be able to continue, either download the tarball from above link, copy all the .jars to JMeter's "lib" and "lib/ext" folders correspondingly and restart JMeter to pick them up.

Recommended way of installing JMeter plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), you will find JSON Path Extractor and JSON Path Assertion in `JSON Plugins` bundle

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager JSON]